# how can I repair a leaking at the water main valve

Tags: water

I noticed a leaking at the water main. idk if it's an easy fix. I wanted to ask the question before calling a plumber.

Comment: It might be as simple as tightening up the packing nut, but with no picture, no way to tell....

Comment: If you're really brave, you can find the city shutoff valve outside.  It is usually 6 feet below the surface and you need a 6 foot tool to turn the valve.   FYI:  I had a plumber replace my main value and he did it under pressure!  (The city valve was under my paved driveway)   He only spilled a cup or so of water.  It was amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your water supply, it may be as easy as calling the water company / department - depends where their responsibility ends and yours starts, in your local area. They might tell you it's your problem, they might send out their plumber to fix it at no additional cost to you beyond your water bill.

Otherwise, valve leaks or replacement can be easy or hard, depending on a lot of details it's hard to see from here. While a picture might help, you never know for sure until you start trying to take it apart. You might need the water company to shut off a valve at the street, if that's where their responsibility ends, so you can put the new valve on inside the house.

Comment: Another reason to contact the water provider is that the nut to be tightened could have a tamper-protection seal. If *you* were to break that seal, it would be presumptive evidence that you tried to tamper with the meter.